# Ubuntu 10.04 on Dell XPS 1330 and many problems

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, dell-xps

I have recently installed Ubuntu 10.04 beside my Windows XP on my laptop:
Dell XPS 1330

I`m now facing some problems with my new OS :

1. The driver for my wireless network card isn't recognized although I have installed the recommended driver which was in Ubuntu Hardware Driver section.
2. When I connect my laptop to my TV using HDMI port, the screen is OK but there is no sound!
3. When by any reason my network cable is unplugged, the whole network service goes down and I have to restart the system.

Thanks in advance for your helps.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)  

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)   

00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)  

00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)    

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)    

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)    

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02) 

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)    

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 02)    

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)    

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)   

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)    

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)    

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f2)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)    

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 02)    

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)    

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)    

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400M GS] (rev a1)    

03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)   

03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)    

03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C843 MMC Host Controller (rev 12)    

03:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)    

03:01.4 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev ff)   

09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)    

0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g (rev 01)           

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****    

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], 
    device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
    Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], 
    device 1: STAC92xx Digital [STAC92xx Digital]
    Subdevices: 1/1

  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'm unable to dig up further Hardware-Specs for that laptop, can you please add the output of `lspci` and `aplay -l` (in code tags) to your question?

Comment: Have you ever upgraded the BIOS? In my case (Dell Latitude D830) the original BIOS version (A02) was almost unusable; docking/undocking froze everything, WLAN could see the access points but not connect them, suspend/resume was buggy... all this with Windows 7, Ubuntu, Debian, openSUSE and PC-BSD. After I upgraded the BIOS to latest version (A14) everything started to work.

Comment: I have also a Windows XP beside my Ubuntu and I have no problem there, But yes you are right It can see the access points but cannot connect to them. Do you think the BIOS might be the problem although there is no problem in my XP?

Comment: I don't see an audio controller for your HDMI connection in the `lspci` output, only the on-board audio. What device does XP use for HDMI audio?

Comment: I think it uses my graphic card itself.